# Confidence interval 100 coin tosses, 52 heads?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, bernoulli-distribution

I am really confused about the confidence interval for n=100 tosses and k=52 heads. If I estimate the probability $\hat{p}$:

$\hat{p} = \frac{52}{100} = 0.52$

$Var(\hat{p}) = pq = 0.52 * 0.48 = 0.2496$, being a bernoulli process

$\sigma = \sqrt{Var(\hat{p})} = 0.5$

$SE = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{0.5}{10} = 0.05 $

$CI = 0.52 ± Z_{0.90} * 0.05 = [0.44, 0.60] $

This seems correct to me. However, when I calculate the confidence interval for the actual number of heads I get:

${X} = 52$

$Var(X) = npq = 100 * 0.52 * 0.48 = 24.96$, being a binomial distribution

$\sigma = \sqrt{Var(X)} = 5$

$SE = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{5}{10} = 0.5 $

$CI = 52 ± Z_{0.90} * 0.5 = [51.17, 52.82] $. I would expect this to be $[44, 60]$ as in my previous result.

Why are these two confidence intervals different?

Thank you!